# Is there a rest api to get all Acumatica General Ledger transactions for a period? Also one to get list of configured branches?

Tags: acumatica

I need to call a rest api to get list of all GL transactions for all accounts for selected period. AccountDetailInquiry just gives one account at a time - that requires too many calls to get data for all accounts. Also a rest api to get list of branches in a company. There soup services for these, but I want to use rest api calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Generic Inquiry (GI) to select the data you are looking for, and then call GI that with a REST API.